# Make div clickable in a nested div

Tags: javascript, function, html, click

I have a `<div>` with an ID - **button2div**. It is over another `<div>` which has its background changed using **JS**.

```
<div id="button2div" onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor:pointer;"></div>
```

I can to add a URL to `button2div` using JS as a nested function.

```
addEventHandler(divarea1, 'mouseover', function () {     
    divbanner.style.backgroundImage ='url(URL To banner)';
    buttondiv.style.backgroundImage ='url(URL To Button Background)';
    $("button1div").click(function(){
        window.location = 'http://google.com';
    });
});
```

This does not work. 
**Note:** the `addEventHandle`r is from `JQuery`.

How do I make this work? Thanks.

Comment: button1div will be rebind event on every mouse move :(

Comment: $("#button1div") if "button1div" is an id

Answer (score 2):

Your missing a # (I presume), try this:

```
$("#button1div").click(function(){
window.location = 'http://google.com';
});
```

The # is a selector which represents your searching for an element which has the id given in the selector.
I.a. #mydiv searches for an element with the id 'mydiv'

Answer (score 0):

missing # but you should not bind event in another event like that

```
addEventHandler(divarea1, 'mouseover', function () {     
  divbanner.style.backgroundImage ='url(URL To banner)';
  buttondiv.style.backgroundImage ='url(URL To Button Background)';
}); 

$("#button1div").click(function(){
   window.location = 'http://google.com';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example with nested spans
http://jsfiddle.net/dG26F/

```
$('span').click(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('data-content')); 
    return false;
});

<span data-content="Hot Dog">
    Hot
    <span data-content="Dog">Dog</span>
</span>

span{
    padding: 10px;
    margin:5px;
    background-color:#c67605;
    display:inline-block;
}
span span{
    background-color:#3a87ad;
}
```